# How to communicate backend status messages to frontend?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task

I have a WPF project and a Console one, the point of the WPF is to be the frontend UI and the console application is the logic that does the actual work.

In my backend I have a class with a method that does the work.

```
public static class BackendClass
{
    public static void DoWork(ref string output)
    {
        //actual work
    }
}
```

From the MVVM frontend my view model starts a task for this method and I want to be able to show status messages on the frontend about it. Things like "Started work.", "Doing so-and-so.", "Finished." and etc.

The code in my view model is:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static string backendOutput;

    public string BackendOutput
    {
        get => backendOutput;

        set
        {
            if (backendOutput != value)
            {
                backendOutput = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BackendOutput");
            }
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand ExecuteCommand { get; private set; }
    Task executionTask;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        executionTask = new Task(() => BackendClass.DoWork(ref BackendOutput));
    }

    void OnExecute()
    {
        executionTask.Start();
        ExecuteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    bool CanExecute()
    {
        return (executionTask.Status != TaskStatus.Running &&
                executionTask.Status != TaskStatus.WaitingToRun);
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The "BackendOutput" property is data binded to a text block in the WPF window.

I was thinking of passing the "BackendOutput" property so the "DoWork" method can append its status messages to it, thus raising the changed event, updating the frontend.
However if I try to assign it outside of the constructor I get the error that a property can't be a field initializer or something like that and in this case I get "property can't be passed as a ref parameter".

So how should I alert the frontend of what status messages the back is pumping?

Comment: Have a look at `IProgress<T>` See Stephen Cleary's blog [link here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewModel communicates with View via PropertyChanged event. So Model also can have an event. ViewModel subscribes to that event, updates property with event data, View gets updated.

Events are kind of protected delegates. So as a first step try to introduce a delegate:

```
public static void DoWork(Action<string> notifier)
{
    notifier("output value");
}
```

and

```
executionTask = new Task(() => BackendClass.DoWork(str => { BackendOutput = str; }));
```

Comment: I'm not getting something - `Action<string>` means `notifier` should take a string parameter and return void. So why are  you calling it with no parameter?

Comment: @mathgenius, because I wrote entire thing in browser, without ide, and missed obvious lack of output? :D

Comment: I figured something as much. :)
But now I don't understand - giving the action "output value" isn't going to change "BackendOutput", I tested what you wrote and nothing happens.

Comment: @mathgenius, "nothing happens" - I find this strange. I expect `OnExecute` to be called, and then BackendOutput to be updated from task

Comment: D'oh! My bad, I wasn't calling it properly. It updates just fine, sorry! :)